# Spring Cloud Stream - unable to serialize java class (works for java record)

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-function

Hi I am having an issue with new functional spring cloud stream...

I have a basic example:

```
@Autowired
    private StreamBridge streamBridge;

    @PostMapping("/publish/{topic}")
//  fails
    public boolean publish(@RequestBody MessageClass msg, @PathVariable String topic) {
//  works
//  public boolean publish(@RequestBody MessageRecord msg, @PathVariable String topic) {
        return this.streamBridge.send(topic, msg);
    }
```

Trying to simply as much as possible this is my java class:

```
public class MessageClass {

    private String key;
    private String content;

    public MessageClass(String key, String content) {
        this.key = key;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public MessageClass() {
    }

    public String content() {
        return content;
    }

    public String key() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

and record:

```
public record MessageRecord(String key, String content) {}
```

This fails for the MessageClass but succeeds with MessageRecord.

Relevant stack trace (I think, full below):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class io.enfuse.streamerrorexample.pkg.MessageClass cannot be cast to class [B (io.enfuse.streamerrorexample.pkg.MessageClass is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; [B is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
        at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer.serialize(ByteArraySerializer.java:19) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.1.jar:na]
```

See repo here: https://github.com/andyrewwer/spring-cloud-stream-error-example/settings/access

What is the difference between the java class and record and why does it work for record but not class?

Full stack trace:

```
2022-06-19 18:04:14.361 ERROR 70401 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$ProducerConfigurationMessageHandler@32e459ed]; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't convert value of class io.enfuse.streamerrorexample.pkg.MessageClass to class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer specified in value.serializer, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=io.enfuse.streamerrorexample.pkg.MessageClass@1dacd968, headers={id=fbe5d434-cd95-00b2-51ca-88a5f3b0f867, contentType=application/json, target-protocol=kafka, timestamp=1655687054356}]] with root cause

java.lang.ClassCastException: class io.enfuse.streamerrorexample.pkg.MessageClass cannot be cast to class [B (io.enfuse.streamerrorexample.pkg.MessageClass is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; [B is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
        at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer.serialize(ByteArraySerializer.java:19) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:62) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:954) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:914) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.1.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.send(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:993) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.6.jar:2.8.6]
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:655) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.6.jar:2.8.6]
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:429) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.6.jar:2.8.6]
        at org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(KafkaProducerMessageHandler.java:513) ~[spring-integration-kafka-5.5.12.jar:5.5.12]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:136) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.12.jar:5.5.12]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.12.jar:5.5.12]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder$SendingHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:1074) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.12.jar:5.5.12]
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.12.jar:5.5.12]
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.12.jar:5.5.12]
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.12.jar:5.5.12]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.12.jar:5.5.12]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.12.jar:5.5.12]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.12.jar:5.5.12]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge.send(StreamBridge.java:235) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge.send(StreamBridge.java:170) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge.send(StreamBridge.java:150) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
        at io.enfuse.streamerrorexample.pkg.StreamService.publish(StreamService.java:23) ~[main/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:4.0.FR]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:4.0.FR]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:an]
```

Comment: How does it fail? Compile error? runtime error? What is the error message / stacktrace?

Comment: The class doesn't implement `Serializable` a record is automatically serializable.

Comment: Does this require more than just public class MessageClass implements Serializable {...} -- if so that did not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

A bit old, but if someone needs an answer:
The problem is the class doesn't have getters:

```
public String content() {
    return content;
}

public String key() {
    return key;
}
```

In records it's possible because Jackson know abou them and treat them differently, but normal classes should have the good old getters (or you should tell Jackson about it):

```
public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public String getKey() {
    return key;
}
```